# MigLayout issue while setting position explicitly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I have a problem in MigLayout when setting the position of a component explicitly (with id.x and id.y constraints) and resizing the container where the component is added. Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swing.*;

public class MigClass extends JFrame {

    MigClass(String title) {
        super(title);
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        final JPanel content = new JPanel(new MigLayout()); 

        final JLabel l1 = new JLabel("A label");
        content.add(l1, "push, center, top, id l1");
        l1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                final JTextField editor = new JTextField(5);
                content.add(editor, "pos l1.x l1.y");
                editor.setVisible(true);
                l1.setVisible(false);
                editor.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                        if(e.getKeyCode() == (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                            l1.setText(editor.getText());
                            editor.setVisible(false);
                            l1.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    }                   
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }

        });
        add(content, "grow, push, span");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MigClass gui = new MigClass(null);
    }
}
```

The `JTextField` editor hasn't the right position (it should overlap l1's position) if the constraint `"push"` is added to the label (this happens only if the frame is enlarged). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: hmm ... could be a bug. Curious: why don't you use a grow on the column constraint (thus obviating the push on the component constraint)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly stated in the documentation but you cannot 
mix relative positioning with the grid structure. Either use
the relative positioning or the normal grid structure.

There is no need to have two `MigLayout` managers set. The
panel can be simply added to the central area of the 
`BorderLayout`.

I came up with a solution that utilizes the `hidemode` constraint.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutReplaceEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutReplaceEx() {

        initUI();

        setSize(300, 250);
        setTitle("Replace component");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("A label");
        pnl.add(lbl, "cell 0 0, hidemode 3");        

        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        pnl.add(field, "cell 0 0, hidemode 3");
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {

                    lbl.setText(field.getText());
                    field.setVisible(false);
                    lbl.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });

        field.setVisible(false);

        lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                lbl.setVisible(false);
                field.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        add(pnl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutReplaceEx ex = new MigLayoutReplaceEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The example shows a label on the window. Clicking on the label we hide the label
and show a text field. When we press enter in the field, the text field is hidden
and the label is shown, copying the new text from the text field.

In `hidemode 3` invisible components do not participate in the layout. We can
therefore dynamically show components in the same cell where the other component
is always hidden.